# Ruby on rails facebook canvas app No route matches [POST] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am trying to build a facebook app using koala in rails. 
I am booting my app on localhost using webrick @ port 3000. My canvas url is `http://localhost:3000/`
However I can use my app from my browser typing `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser and everything works (I can auth user,get access token,pull data).
However when I try to access my app from facebook via my computer (sandbox mode is disabled), typing `http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx`, I get following error instead of my app's

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
    root GET /                                   home#index
    home_index GET /home/index(.:format)         home#index
    home_callback GET /home/callback(.:format)   home#callback
```

Comment: showing your routes will definitely help.

Comment: I see that you uses only **GET** requests, but where is **POST** request handler?

Comment: I actually followed this tutorial `https://github.com/banane/sample-koala-rails-app‎` There is nothing about the facebook's post request. And what data is  posting by facebook anyway?

Comment: Added `  post '/' => 'home#index'` on routes.rb Now if I send a post request via curl, it shows the index page of my app, but facebook is showing a blank page now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any routes to match!
Every request by facebook is coming as POST-verb

in your case, the following will catch it

````
post "/" => "home#index"

Answer (score 0):

Please give the url in facebook canvas with ip address like this

http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3000

and you also use this url on your browser

That will definably work for you.

Comment: My app is in my localhost so I tried to add `http://127.0.0.1:3000` . And facebook shows the error is `Canvas URL cannot be a Facebook URL.

Secure Canvas URL cannot be a Facebook URL.`

Comment: you have use ur ip address rather then "localhost" in facebook call back url also.

Comment: Spefified a domain on my /etc/hosts file, But same old blank page, btw on webrick's logfile,it shows the page was rendered! `#<ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods::NullSession::NullSessionHash:0x000000036c1c88><<< session
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/home (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need htttps url. facebook only allows https url.